# Can not find 64-bit Oracle Client Library when connection to Oracle Cloud Autonomous Database with Django

Tags: oracle, cx-oracle, django-database, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, python-oracledb

Following this [tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/connecting-to-oracle-cloud-autonomous-database-with-django#), I am getting the below error when I try to `python manage.py runserver`

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 0x0001): tried: 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
```

I have installed both [cx_oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html) and [oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) and nothing has worked. I have Oracle Instant Client for macOS (Intel x86) installed and the wallet is pulled down in the correct location as well.

Are there environment variables I can set to tell with cx_oracle or oracledb where the Oracle libraries are located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see this error with python-oracledb, then your application contains a call to `init_oracle_client()`.  You could remove all such calls and use the default Thin mode.

If you want to continue with python-oracledb 'Thick' mode, or you are using the older version of the driver (cx_Oracle), then change your `init_oracle_client()` calls and pass the `lib_dir` parameter.  (This works on macOS Intel and Windows).  See [Setting the Oracle Client Library Directory on macOS](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#setting-the-oracle-client-library-directory-on-macos).  For example:

```
import oracledb

oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir="/Users/your_username/Downloads/instantclient_19_8")
```

To connect to Oracle ADB, be aware that the syntax differs between  python-oracledb Thin & Thick modes.  See [Connecting to Oracle Cloud Autonomous Databases](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connecting-to-oracle-cloud-autonomous-databases).

Comment: Thanks! I needed ...

cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir = "/path/to/instantclient_19_8", config_dir="/path/to/location/of/tnsnames.ora")

...Marking your response as answer as it got me there.